# How to delete history of Totem and Gedit in gnome shell?

Tags: gedit, totem, history

How can I delete history of Totem and Gedit in gnome shell?

I can not find a menu option to do this, unlike in gnome 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find both `recent-used.xbel` and the `totem` folder in the following locations;

- your home folder
- `.local/share folder`

If you delete the `recent-used.xbel` file and the `totem` folder, all of the history of your general applications and totem will be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Totem now uses Gnome Tracker to pick what videos to display in the "Recent" tab. According to https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Tracker/Documentation/First5Minutes, Tracker's db can be cleared by running `tracker-control -r`

You can also run `tracker-preferences`, `System` tab and click the "Yes, remove all of my indexed data" button.